# What's the best way to store variables in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm using asp.net and c#.
I have some variable like `CurrentCulture`, `SignedinUserEmail`, `MenuItemID` for for each page that are used in different method and events, which way is the best for holding their values?

```
private string _CurrentCulture;
private string CurrentCulture
{
    get
    {
        return _CurrentCulture;
    }
    set
    {
        _CurrentCulture = value;
    }
}
```

or

```
private string CurrentCulture
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["CurrentCulture"] == null)
        {
            return "en-UK";
        }
        else
        {
            return ((string)ViewState["CurrentCulture"]);
        }
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["CurrentCulture"] = value;
    }
}
```

their values might assign by query string or another local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can best use each one as:

- Save it to  **viewstate** if you need to have it after the post back. If you do not make post back there is no reason to save it there.
- Save it **to a variable** if you like to get it from the page it self, or to send it to other custom controls on the page.
- Save it **to the session** if you like to use it on other pages - for example if some user select a language that prefer, then save that selection on session and use it on the next pages.
- Use the **url parameters** if you won the user to be able to save the url, and together keep that parameters.

The `CurrentCulture`, `SignedinUserEmail` is better to saved on session because you want to use it on every call, on every page view, with and with out post back.

Comment: thanks Arison, I know about this, my problem is i don't know how i should store coming values to a page load , I want to store them once and use them in different methods and event just in that code behind. saving in Property can't not be unique?

Comment: @Ramtin if you won to use them only on the page life cycle, just use a simple public variable.

Comment: Aristons If i store those variable in public variables will they be unique for different users that access to that page at same time?

Comment: @Ramtin Is they are NOT static, they will be unique and live for the page cycle only. If they are static they will be the same for all users for each pool. If they are on session they will be unique for each user and they live for the time of the user session.